# Trouble passing spilled range to VBA - Only getting Application-defined or object-defined error

Tags: excel, vba, spill-range

I'm having an issue passing a Spill array to VBA. The range is defined by as name "ListCurJobs" and the equation

`=UNIQUE(FILTER(CtrlSht!$B:$B,CtrlSht!$B:$B<>""))`

Testing the named range on the worksheet using "=ListCurJobs" returns the spilled range as expected.

I am trying to pass this into VBA using

```
Sub ListJobs
Dim listCurJobs() As Variant

n = Worksheets("CtrlSht").Range("listCurJobs").Rows.Count

ReDim listCurJobs(n, 1)

listCurJobs = Worksheets("CtrlSht").Range("listCurJobs")

End Sub
```

This works fine for standard arrays, but with the spill array I get the error : *Application-defined or object-defined error*.

EDIT: Follow up - I managed to fix this by changing the named range listCurJobs to use an Offset function

`=OFFSET(CtrlSht!$E$1,0,0,CtrlSht!$D$1)`

where CtrlSht!$D$1 is counting all items in E via

`=COUNTA(E1#)`

and E1 has the spill function that I was trying to use in the named range i.e.

`=UNIQUE(FILTER(CtrlSht!$B:$B,CtrlSht!$B:$B<>""))`

Whatever is causing the original error, these additional steps seem to avoid it.

Comment: Did you try `Dim listCurJobs as Variant    listCurJobs = Worksheets("CtrlSht").Range("listCurJobs").Value` ? This should return a 2D array

Comment: Hi @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns - Just tried this and still getting the same error. Also, adding a watch to ```Worksheets("CtrlSht").Range("listCurJobs").Value``` returns the same problem.

Comment: Actually - I've just solved it via a workaround. Some bug perhaps with the new spill functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to fix this by changing the named range `listCurJobs` to use an `Offset` function:

```
=OFFSET(CtrlSht!$E$1,0,0,CtrlSht!$D$1)
```

Where `CtrlSht!$D$1` is counting all items in `E` via:

```
=COUNTA(E1#)
```

And `E1` has the `spill` function that I was trying to use in the named range; i.e.,

```
=UNIQUE(FILTER(CtrlSht!$B:$B,CtrlSht!$B:$B<>""))
```

Whatever is causing the original error, these additional steps seem to avoid it.